# Debugging Missing Target Make File

Tags: unix, makefile

Lets say you are debugging a make file and you only want to run the second half.

So, for example, you do not have code to make the file: vertex.cpp (you have commented this out in the code, but indeed vertext.cpp does exist in the directory). But vertex.cpp is required for targets to be built downstream.

How would you go about running the make file in those conditions?

Comment: If target file exists and there is no implicit rules confusing make to rebuild it (e.g. `.y` file with the same name but higher modification date can cause make to try `yacc` on it), then there should be no problem. If it is, check `make -d` (a lot of text, search by filename helps).

Comment: updated the question to clarify what I mean, not sure if there was a misunderstanding

Comment: Once again, it isn't a problem. If I remove all pattern rules compiling `.cpp` to `.o` but I already have `.o`s - linking will go fine, it requires no further makefile modification. If `.cpp` is newer than `.o` however, make may decide to recompile it either way because it have implicit pattern `%.cpp: %.o`. It is all the same for `.anything=>.cpp`. What exact error message you getting?